# How to authorize depending on the request?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I am currently adding permissions/roles/authorization to a Laravel application.

In the application's database are users, companies and products. Companies have many users and a product belongs to a company.

Now I want to authorize company users, to create a product for their company.

In my **ProductController.php** I have something like this:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $company = Company::findOrFail($request->get('company_id'));
    return view('product.create', compact('company');
}
```

One option would be to use `Gate::authorize()` after getting the company and pass the `$company` to the authorize-method.

Question: But how can I solve this, if I don't want to use `Gate::authorize()`. So in case I want to use **policies**?

Another Question: I see several ways to authorize: `Gate::authorize()`, policies, StoreProduct's `authorize()`, ...
Which one should I use? Should I always implement StoreProduct's `authorize()` event if I use **policies** for example?

Comment: Do the user and product both belong to only one company?

Comment: @rakete you can create `permission` like `manage product` or individual like `create product` and `update product` etc. User `Request` classes to check if user has permission. Let me know if interested in this approach and I will add some sample code

Comment: @Bryan companis have many users. Product has one company.

Comment: @MikeRoss Hm, I already created the permissions. It's not the problem to check for the permission. The problem is, that the model which decided if the user is authorized (user's company) will passed as company_id.

Comment: If your user only belongs to one company I would rely on the relation(assuming you have a belongsTo in the `User` model): `$company = $request->user()->company;`

Comment: Yes, of cause... But how can I access $request from the ProductPolicy?

Comment: `Gate::authorize()` does use policies, and `authorize()` uses them too. Show your route for this create method, please, and the policy for it.

Answer (score 3):

You can have the `create` ability on the `ProductPolicy` take a Company instance as an argument and you can then check that the User belongs to that Company in the policy:

```php
use App\Company;
use App\User;

class ProductPolicy
{
    public function create(User $user, Company $company)
    {
        return $user->company_id === $company->id;
    }

    ...
}
```

You can call `authorize` in your Controller to use the `ProductPolicy` to authorize the User. These authorization methods can take an array as the second argument which allows you to send additional data [the first argument will be the model for the policy, in this case it doesn't take an instance, but we still need it to know which model's policy we want so it takes the class name]. This will check the `create` ability on the policy for Product and pass it an additional value of `$company`:

```php
use App\Company;
use App\Product;
...
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $company = Company::findOrFail($request->input('company_id'));

    $this->authorize('create', [Product::class, $company]);

    return view('product.create', compact('company');
}
```

Remember to register the Policy for the Product model.

You have options for how you want to do authorization, that is why there are different methods to achieve it. Depends what you prefer or what fits your current need.